# Why are names of proteins not in dictionaries and not considered to be words?

Tags: dictionaries

It makes sense to not include unwieldy scientific names in dictionaries, as they would cause dictionaries to swell in size unreasonably. However, I was wondering how and when this decision was made and why its exclusions are so extreme; I was unable to find the definition of the word "rubisco", which refers to one of the most important proteins in biology, in the Merriam Webster dictionary (rubisco allows photosynthesis to occur)

Why do dictionaries leave out all lengthy scientific vocabulary indiscriminately?
Also: it is my understanding that protein names are not considered words at all. Is this true of all proteins? Why is this?

Comment: From a Wikipedia article on the subject: "The term 'Rubisco' was coined humorously in 1979 by David Eisenberg at a seminar. The abbreviation came from the full name (**R**ibulose-1,5-**bis**phosphate **c**arboxylase/**o**xygenase)." That sounds like biology jargon to me. I don't expect jargon to be in a general purpose dictionary.  I use the word "Dockerize" every day, but I don't expect it to be in Merriam-Webster.  Of course, new words are added to dictionaries: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/new-words-in-the-dictionary. How they choose their new words could be worth asking.

Comment: "Not considered words at all" is the strangest thing I have read all week. Two very simple questions: 1) not considered *by whom*, and 2) *what* are they considered instead. Smells? Colors? Melodies? Any name — *any* name —, by definition, is a word. If it isn't a word, it cannot be a name.

Comment: It is odd that they are not considered words, but consider this quote: "However, in the past it has been disputed whether or not it is a real word - proteins are named after the chemicals involved in making them." -https://www.digitalspy.com/fun/a444700/longest-word-has-189819-letters-takes-three-hours-to-pronounce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is based on a false assumption.

*Hemoglobin* is in my dictionary (*New Oxford American Dictionary*). Also *rubisco*: "an enzyme present in plant chloroplasts..."     Many dictionaries include only a selection of the more common words, rather than all words.  On-line you can consult many dictionaries.

For unusual words, try Google search or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

They're not there for exactly the reason you gave. Specialized language of professional fields is too esoteric for a book for the general public.

Comment: Plus, 30 to 60,000 protein names as well as hundreds of thousands of chemical names would clog up dictionaries to the point of their being useless for finding common words. Even the names of most bacteria, fungi and plants are left out.